# Compiling several files with babel

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, wildcard, babeljs

Simple example: I want to use babel (via grunt) to compile all of the files in a folder without having to specify the files one by one. How do I do this? I have looked at basically all of Babel's docs (and lots of other places) and found nothing.

I know I can do this:

```
'dist/folder/a.js': 'folder/a.js',
'dist/folder/b.js': 'folder/b.js',
'dist/folder/c.js': 'folder/c.js'
```

but what I want to do is something like:

```
'dist/folder/': 'folder/*.js',
```

I also tried the following approach but it stops after the first file:

```
'dist/folder/alltogethernow.js': 'folder/*.js',
```

How do I do this? I don't really care if it's all in the same file or separate files as the files will eventually be merged together anyway. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm talking about babel 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map each individual file you could use:

```
babel: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        presets: ['es2015'] 
    },
    dist: {
         files: [{
            expand: true,  
            src: ['folder/*.js'], 
            dest: 'dist'
          }]
    }
},
```

Comment: Are you getting some error? Try adding presets: ['es2015'] to the options.

Comment: thanks, that worked. I was using the _env_ preset which includes es2015 transforms but for some reason it doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: I assumed the cause was that since babel 6 changed a lot of stuff that syntax was now obsolete. apparently, it's just random preset differences.